# ADO.NET CRUD Methods

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have problems to give my ASP.NET MVC project a good structure.

In contrast to other MVC applications, I was against the Entity Framework even if there had been a good structure for my project.

But now, my question is, what is the best practise to handle all my CRUD methods so, that they don't repeat thereself. Is it normal, to write methods like "GiveMeAllProductsStartingWithLetterP" (just an example ;-)) and write my SQL-String in there? I hope you understand my question. Or does realy somebody write generic SQL-Methods for CRUD like: RetrieveEntity(string EntityName, ColumnList clmnList, int NumberOfColumns)?

Best regards

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what you're asking, isn't that what LINQ and built-in EF functions are for?

Answer (score 0):

can you try EntitySetController instead of ApiController? [check this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/11/02/odata-in-webapi-microsoft-asp-net-web-api-odata-0-2-0-alpha-release.aspx) for examples implementation.